# UV Editor acting strange

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

[image: A round disc shape like a squashed bowling ball, and a UV looking like a broken kite]

Hi everyone, I've got this shape here and I've marked seams around the edges but the UV.. comes out looking like this. Any idea what's going on? I've tried restarting the program, resetting the UV and trying again. It was working at one point, but I had to edit the shape and it hasn't worked since

I'm hoping I just broke a setting somewhere by accident. I'm on 3.2

Can't update software as it's a university PC but I could send the file to myself and try at home tonight if that might be the solution as my own laptop is on 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some (or all) vertices of UV map **Pinned** (see Red points) ... go to *UV Editor* and Unpin (ALt+P) them first ... than Unwrap ...

[image]

Comment: what is pinned vertexes used for sir ?

Comment: Thank you this was the issue! Never come across those before :)

Comment: @hamed.design ... [Blender Manual > Unwrap > Pin](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/uv/editing.html#pin-unpin)